# Bootstrap Modal with link not closing properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, turbolinks

i'm using the bootstrap modal in my rails application with a link in it (my modal shows an overview of a booking, the link directs to the details page). Clicking the details link is alright but when going back with the browser, I have to reload the page because nothing is clickable anymore. It seems as if the modal wasn't closed before clicking the details link.
Adding "data-dismiss" to the details links doesn't work.

Maybe it's an issue with turbolinks? Thanks!

Comment: I would add javascript to handle that.  You just need an on click event handler for that link that closes the modal and then follows the link.